# How to install particular go command in docker container?

Tags: docker, go, dependencies

I want to use `go mod graph` inside the docker container to generate dependency graph in go repository. I only use that command and not use the other go functionalities. I have try the other tools like godegraph, gomod, dept and nothing can do better than `go mod graph` . Currently I installed all the go functionalities and add about 400MB of my docker image size.

Question : Can I reduce the size of the docker container by installing spesific command in golang ? Or can I get the binary of `go mod graph` so its can reduce the size of the container?

Comment: the `go mod` sub command is part of the go compiler binary provided in the docker images https://hub.docker.com/_/golang. As long as they expose a go version >= 1.11. https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

Comment: if you need extra small docker go images, take a look to alpine base versions.

Comment: okey i'll try it, thankyou!

Comment: try using a [multi stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  Build the dependency graph in an intermediate image, then `COPY` from that image only the output of `go mod graph`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need Go when executing your image (docker run), but only need it for building your image (docker build), then, as commented, use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds).

Here is an example: "[Create lean Docker images using the Builder Pattern](https://medium.com/@kaperys/create-lean-docker-images-using-the-builder-pattern-37fe2b5d97d4)" from [Mike Kaperys](https://twitter.com/_kaperys):

> Each `FROM` instruction defines a new base image for the following instructions, and begins a new build stage.
> Before multi-stage builds it was possible to to achieve the same effect, but the process required 2 Dockerfiles.
>
> Using multi-stage builds allows you to selectively copy files between build stages — this is the basis of the builder pattern.

See [`kaperys/blog/docker-builder-pattern`](https://github.com/kaperys/blog/tree/master/docker-builder-pattern)

```
FROM golang:1.16
COPY . /go/src/github.com/kaperys/blog/docker-builder-pattern
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/kaperys/blog/docker-builder-pattern
RUN go get && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o server .

FROM scratch
LABEL maintainer="Mike Kaperys <mike@kaperys.io>"
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/kaperys/blog/docker-builder-pattern/server /opt/kaperys/vision/server
COPY --from=0 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
ADD html/ /opt/kaperys/vision/html
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /opt/kaperys/vision
ENTRYPOINT [ "./server" ]
```

That way, you start from an image where Go is already installed (included `go mod`), then you build your actual image from any other one you want (including, in this example, "[scratch](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360004012857-What-are-docker-scratch-based-images-)").

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but i use go command inside the container for analyze go repository, so i cannot use multi-stage-build since its only for build go app and get the binary file

Comment: @MuhammadZunanAlfikri Do you mean your image is for a development environment which needs some go command?

Comment: Yes, currently my smallest way is using ```COPY --from=golang:alpine /usr/local/go/ /usr/local/go/```  and add around 300mb to my docker image. Still search the other way to reduce the size

Comment: @MuhammadZunanAlfikri I would rather starti with the official Golang image (https://hub.docker.com/_/golang), possibly the alpine version, and add my stuff on top of it.